# Limit of a function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

The limit as $x$ tends to infinity of $(\sqrt{x^2+mx}-\sqrt{x^2+nx})=\frac{m-n}{2}$ 
How would you go about proving this? I have tried multiplying by the conjugate on the top and bottom but it did not make things any clearer. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The method of multiplying top and bottom by the "conjugate" sum of radicals does succeed.  Perhaps for future Questions you should include such work, so Readers can see the point at which a difficulty was reached.

Answer (score 4):

Your way is just fine.
$$\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+mx}-\sqrt{x^2+nx})(\sqrt{x^2+mx}+\sqrt{x^2+nx})}{\sqrt{x^2+mx}+\sqrt{x^2+nx}}$$
$$= \frac{(x^2+mx)-(x^2+nx)}{\sqrt{x^2+mx}+\sqrt{x^2+nx}}$$
$$= \frac{(m-n)x}{\sqrt{x^2+mx}+\sqrt{x^2+nx}}$$
$$= \frac{m-n}{\sqrt{(x^2/x^2)+(mx/x^2)}+\sqrt{(x^2/x^2)+(nx/x^2)}}$$
$$=\frac{m-n}{\sqrt{1+(m/x)}+\sqrt{1+(n/x)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{x^2+mx}-\sqrt{x^2+nx}=x(\sqrt{1+\frac mx}-\sqrt{1+\frac nx}),$$
and by Taylor
$$=x(1+\frac m{2x}+o(\frac1x)-1-\frac n{2x}-o'(\frac1x))$$
$$=\frac{m-n}2+xo''(\frac1x).$$

Comment: @MathLover: your first implication after "I think, I can write" is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It will help if you perform the conjugation,

$$f(x)= \frac{x(m-n)}{\sqrt{x^2+mx}+\sqrt{x^2+nx}}$$

$$f(x) =\frac{x(m-n)}{x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{m}{x}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{n}{x}}\right)}$$

You can go on from there. It should be rather straightforward.